# Polymer: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Tags: polymer

I will get an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" and I dont know why if I use
the Polymer function.

I can't use `document.querySelector('paper-shadow').setZ(3);`, because then I get this error: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setZ' of null" It

```
<link rel="import" href="components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="components/paper-shadow/paper-shadow.html">
<link rel="import" href="paper-input-search.html">
<link href="components/core-focusable/core-focusable.html" rel="import">
<link href="components/core-collapse/core-collapse.html" rel="import">
<link href="components/core-icons/core-icons.html" rel="import">
<link href="components/core-menu/core-menu.html" rel="import">
<link href="components/paper-button/paper-button.html" rel="import">
<link href="components/paper-dropdown/paper-dropdown.html" rel="import">
<link href="components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" rel="import">
<link href="components/paper-item/paper-item.html" rel="import">
<link href="components/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.html" rel="import">

<polymer-element name="website-card" attributes="link searchatt canExtend extends">
  <template>
    <style> (...)
    </style>    

    <paper-shadow z="{{shadowValue}}" fit></paper-shadow>
    <div onMouseOver="{{overShadow}}" onClick="location.href='{{link}}'" class="card-header" layout horizontal center>
      <paper-ripple fit></paper-ripple>
      <content select="img"></content>
      <content select="h2"></content>      
    </div>
    (...)
    <div layout horizontal>
    <paper-input-search style="width:100%" searchaddr="{{searchatt}}" label="search" hidden?="{{searchatt == 'no'}}"></paper-input-search>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script> 
        Polymer('website-card', {
            publish:{
                shadowValue: 1
            },
            overShadow: function(event, detail, sender){
            shadowValue = 3;
            console.log(shadowValue);
        }
        });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things going on here. paper-shadow has done some optimizations such that data binding doesn't work automatically, and you need to call `setZ`, as it appears that you've noticed. Doing a straight `document.querySelector` doesn't work because of the shadow dom. The solution is to combine `setZ` with `[this.$][1]`. So in the html:

`<paper-shadow id='shadow' z='2'></paper-shadow>`

And then in your javascript:

`this.$.shadow.setZ(shadowValue)`